# SDL - Difference between SDL_GetRenderer and SDL_CreateRenderer

Tags: c++, c, graphics, sdl, sdl-2

Both the functions `SDL_GetRenderer(SDL_Window*)` and `SDL_CreateRenderer(SDL_Window*, int, Uint32)` seem to do the same thing: return a pointer to `SDL_Renderer` from the window. However, **what method is more appropriate for the task**? The [SDL Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer) does not provide much information on where which method should be used, so please explain what each method does, how they differ and where they should be used.

Comment: I assume you first need to Create a Renderer before you can Get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SDL_CreateRenderer` allows you to create a renderer for a window by specifying some options. It's stored in the specific window data which you can query with `SDL_GetRenderer` (so the latter is equivalent to `(SDL_Renderer *)SDL_GetWindowData(window, SDL_WINDOWRENDERDATA)`)

If you call `SDL_GetRenderer` without having created it beforehand, you'll get a NULL pointer.

If you call `SDL_CreateRenderer` on a window twice, the second call will fail with `SDL_SetError("Renderer already associated with window");` (see line 805).

See [here](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/13ba7364ff90aed77432f035ce1b673ac29ac3d7/src/render/SDL_render.c)